# Xpath: select content from a specific <span> inside an <li>

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I have the following source code:

```
<li nums="1 - 1" price="519.80" class="current">
<span class="col1">1 + </span>
<span class="col2">US $519.80</span>
</li>
```

Now I want to get as a result: US $519.80, so I try to just select the span with col2 but due to the fact that the span with class col2 exists more than one it should be the one that is inside

tag with class current.

I tried it with:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'current') and contains(@class, 'col2')]
```

But I do not get "US $519.80" as a result.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple ***xpath*** expression:

```
//li[@class="current"]/span[@class="col2"]/text()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I replace $node = $finder->query("//li[@class="current"] and /span[@class="col2"]"); WITH $node = $finder->query("//li[@class="current"]/span[@class="col2"]text()"); I get an error.

Comment: works perfect! just had to replace " with '! thank you very much!

Comment: do you know an answer to this: I have the following source code:

    <span id="price" class="fl" itemprop="price">285,90</span>

Now I want to get as a result: 285,90 

I tried it with:

    //span[@class='fl']/span[@id='price']/text()

But I do not get "285,90" as a result. Again its important to ask for id AND class.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: @redsunset, `//span[@id='price']/text()`

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
//span[@class='col2']/text()
```